# Deploying ASP.NET MVC 4 from SVN and building

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on my first ASP.NET MVC 4 app. The client is deploying directly from the SVN repo, which I am pushing from. Can/should I be checking in release builds, or should they be running builds on their end as part of the deploy process. I am wanting to make it as simple for them as possible. Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be checking any builds into a source control repository. Only source code. A build server should be used to precompile the application using the target configuration (Release if you are pushing to production). Also be careful not to leave any production connection strings and urls into the source code you have commited. An innocent developer could checkout the code and do lots of damage without any consciousness.

Comment: Thanks! So are you saying that the release database connection string should *not* be in the repo? If it is not there, does that mean that whoever is deploying needs to manually enter it on the other end?

Comment: Well you can leave the connection string and replace the actual information with few hints as [TypeUsername], [TypePasswordHere] etc

Comment: Or you can use the web configuration transformer. Eg put them in Web.Release.config BY debugging or running from visual studio will not use this transforms, only when you publish.

Comment: Agreed with Tenerezza, web config transformations could be used.